# My laptop sometimes gets darker when I want to brighten the display up and vice versa

Tags: windows, display, brightness

Sometimes when I press the "darken display" or "brighten display" key on my HP 250-G3 it does the opposite.
It doesn't always occur. Sometimes when I turn it on it behaves correctly for the whole time my Laptop runs and sometimes it doesn't behave correctly. It never changed while my laptop was still on and this only has happened on Windows 8-10. It never occur on Linux distributions.

What may be the cause of this problem?

Comment: Sounds like a driver conflict/incompatibility this machine came with what version of Windows?

Comment: Completely anecdotal evidence here, but the HP brightness buttons suck. They take forever to respond and the levels never seem to match what the Windows brightness setting seems to show.

Comment: Has the screen ever been replaced?

Comment: @Ramhound it came with Windows 8 Bing Edition.

Comment: @MichaelFrank I, at least, don't have this issue with the brightness.

Comment: @Appleoddity no the screen got never replaced.

Comment: Most Windows 8 Bing devices were bottom of the barrel machines which mean, unfortunately, Windows 10 support is unlikely.  I would go back to Windows 8 and make sure your use by the current drivers for that OS.

Comment: @Ramhound Windows 10 works perfectly fine for me, except for the brightness setting. Apart from that I never had problems I didn't have on other machines.